# Transaction hash using web3.py received but variable state not changed

Tags: remix, web3.py, python

Trying to send a value to function and set it to a variable.

Making transaction using

```
txn = contractInstact.transact({
        'from': 
Web3.toChecksumAddress("0xc5ce5f52ab724a2996aab373a14c21c3b9c8ece7"),
        'gasPrice': 500000
    }).makeInvestment(1)

 # https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/blob/master/docs/examples.rst 
 # FUNCTION from documentation mentioned above wait_for_receipt

 receipt = self.wait_for_receipt(txn, 1)
```

What I am missing to complete the transaction using Web3.py
because in this function  makeInvestment

```
import "./Relayer.sol";


uint public totalInvested;
bool investmentLaunched;
Relayer relayerObj;
address owner;

// mapping of amount invested by a peer
mapping (address => uint) private peerAmount;

// mapping of peers who invested
mapping (address => uint8) private isInvestedPeer;

// addresses of all invested peers
address[] private investedPeers;

// addresses of all peers
address[] private peers;

constructor() public{
     owner = address(0);
     totalInvested = 0;
     investmentLaunched = false;
     relayerObj = Relayer(0x8B23dEe880Fe20781655734b519dFB0E047020Ad);
 }

function makeInvestment(uint _amount)
    public 
    returns(bool) {
    owner = msg.sender;
    if(validatePeer(owner) == true){
        if(isInvestedPeer[owner] == 0){
            investedPeers.push(owner);
            isInvestedPeer[owner] = 1;
        }
        peerAmount[owner] += _amount;
        totalInvested += peerAmount[owner];
        if(investmentLaunched == true){
            if(investedPeers.length == peers.length){
                relayerObj.triggerEvent(totalInvested, owner);
                return true;
            }
        }
        else{
            relayerObj.triggerEvent(totalInvested, owner);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

// Where validatePeer function (returns bool) is to verify if peer exist in peersAddress array

And this totalInvested variable is Public
called in python as

```
print(peer_wallets_instance.functions.getTotalInvestedAmount().call())
```

but problem this returns 0 (zero).

Thanks

Comment: `makeInvestment` is a `view` function (it returns a value), so nothing will be saved to contract. You are not even returning anything, then why it is described as `view`? You should investigate more about how `view` and `pure` functions are different from the ones which can change contract `state/storage`.  
Or provide more code where all used variables are visible.

Comment: Can you display `status` value on the receipt? Maybe it's failing for some reason. Also, you can use `w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(txn_hash)` instead of writing your own.

Comment: sorry for make Investment function that I missed return statement @Maxpeinas

Comment: All I am creating this transact()
after this, a receipt is mentioned above, I have signed transaction like 

signed = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(dict(receipt), u.normalize_key( privateKey))

and now error occurs : TypeError: from field must match key's 0x78672Bcb4d457863eF6d5593C5d5d1A9A8536aD6, but it was 0x78672bcb4d457863ef6d5593c5d5d1a9a8536ad6

Comment: Transaction receipt mined:

{'blockHash': HexBytes('0x30b912e3032a6c59da59ce067084ae1334d70797e0e4d3085423e1c21bd8c4d0'),
 'blockNumber': 3387,
 'contractAddress': None,
 'cumulativeGasUsed': 41022,
 'from': '0x78672bcb4d457863ef6d5593c5d5d1a9a8536ad6',
 'gasUsed': 41022,
 'logs': [],
 'logsBloom': HexBytes('0x00'),
 'root': '0xd27cee9a7d53681da1b1cbfe40e425b5adee1dc5935007c2681468ec5d4e1d53',
 'to': '0x107a8897b3e664cd02f9684adddbd27bfe9a65f3',
 'transactionHash': HexBytes('0xf21f5e64bf28ad76506aff1d99f134cc71f960e85286b0535f65f51c857dea12'),
 'transactionIndex': 0}

Comment: Your function will not change anything in contract because it's `view` (have `return`). Read more about differences between functions https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/contracts.html#functions . If you changed it already then i don't know why you get this new error.

Comment: @Maxpeinas its mentioned that if a function not declared with View/Pure keyword then its not a VIEW
if still not so, I am going to update functionality, pardon me.

Comment: Further, I have tried this too,

totalInvested += _amount;

but same results. Problem I believe I am unable to sendTransaction to smart contract. See transaction results above. At SIGN TRANSACTION, its creating error in WEB3.PY as code is
signed = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(dict(receipt), u.normalize_key( b'PRIV_KEY'))
and error is 

 TypeError: from field must match key's 0x78672Bcb4d457863eF6d5593C5d5d1A9A8536aD6, but it was 0x78672bcb4d457863ef6d5593c5d5d1a9a8536ad6

Comment: Thanks @carver , I am using WEB3 function now. But still error is to sign and sendRaw transaction.